# Android - No hardware menubutton

Tags: android, tablet

I concluded the newer android tablets doesn't have a hardware Menubutton anymore.

So I was wondering if I have to insert an menu button in my own (fullscreen) app or does android offer a software included menubutton itself (even when my app runs fullscreen)?

(I don't have an android phone/tab myself to test, so I asked here)

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: You probably want to read [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) on the dev blog.

Answer (score 0):

You should move away from menu buttons. It's the new style of Android applications. See [this post from Android developer](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) with the reasons to remove the button and what applications should do instead of offering a menu button.

Answer (score 0):

Most of devices which are not having menu hardware button runs on android 3.0 or greater version
You just need to add one parameter as `showAsAction`.
Which will show menu item on action bar.

Concider reading ActionBar tutorial

Comment: The ActionBar is the bar above the app when it is NOT running in fullscreen, right?
But my app is running in fullscreen so the ActionBar is invisible.

Or is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change the manifest file: you should change targetSdkVersion to <= 10.
Like this:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
```